# Query regarding date which is in Spanish

Tags: vb.net, date

I am trying to automate retrieving data from a website which is in Spanish.

I am getting following string as input `Viernes, 19 de Abril del 2013`

I want to convert the date into this format `#4/19/2013#`.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  What worked and what didn't?

Comment: Well, I tried to set application's current culture to "es-ES".  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES"). I tried to set the max date of datetimepicker using the same format that I have mentioned in the question. But, It didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove "del" from the date then use [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx).

```
DateTime.Parse("Viernes, 19 de Abril 2013", new CultureInfo("es-ES"))
```

returns `4/19/2013`.

Comment: This is most the correct answer, but you could also use `DateTime.Parse`.  Also - strange, but it will recognize "de", but not "del".

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. But, Strangely I am getting "string was not recognized as a valid datetime" error. I have removed both "de" and "del" from the input string. Could you please tell me If I am missing anything.?

Comment: @MattJohnson You're right, just popped open visual studio to try it.  Updated the answer accordingly.